# How to update status in DataTable listing page in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I need without refresh listing page update status of record. I have tried it with full page refresh but I want to an AJAX feature with Laravel rules.

Comment: can you show us some code what you mean?

Comment: Although we need to see some code to fully understand... you could take a look to this: https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax That could be what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Jquery in footer

Add list view page this function

Add your datatables

```
$('#table_user').on('click', '.status_clik', function(){           
 var sid = $(this).attr("sid");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/pageController/updateStatus',
    data: {id: sid},
    success: function(response) { // Change elements in the DOM },
});
});
```

In controller page

```
class PageController {
    public function status(Request $request){
        $id = $request->get('id');
        if($id!=''){
            $geStatus = DB::table('tablename')->where('id', $id)->first();

            $update_data = array('eStatus'=>GET_OPPOSITE_STATUS[$geStatus->eStatus]);
            $update = DB::table('tablename')->where('id', $id)->update($update_data);
            if($update){

                return response()->json(array("status"=>1,"message"=>'Status updated successfully'));

            }else{ return response()->json(array("status"=>0,"message"=>_FAIL_TO_PROCESS)); }
        }else{return response()->json(array("status"=>0,"message"=>_FAIL_TO_PROCESS));}
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to update a record with Ajax you have to implement Ajax in your template and request a controller method that execute the change.

jQuery example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/pageController/updateStatus',
    data: {id: 15, status: 'example'},
    success: function(response) { // Change elements in the DOM },
});
```

*This will post the page ID and status to the updateStatus controller method. On success you can update values in the DOM.*

Controller example:

```
class PageController {
    public function updateStatus(int $id, $status) {
        $page = Page::findOrFail($id);
        $page->status = $status;
        $page->save();

        return $page->status;
    }
}
```

*In the controller you search for the given ID in the Page model. Then you update the status, save it, and return the new status so you can use it in the front-end.*